# Setting a button's size relative to the space available?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my first app with WPF/XAML so I might be doing things wrong.
[image: photo]

How can I make the home button (the one with the border) always be 50% (no matter the size of the window) of that horizontal space (defined by the column + row - so 50% of that quarter of the screen)? I tried doing that using a Viewbox and setting a max-width, but I don't think that's the proper thing to do.

```
<Window x:Class="introducereDAC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:introducereDAC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Divide et Impera" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#FF00000F">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Content="home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF00000F" FontFamily="./#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" FontSize="5"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15 30 15 15">
            <Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light" FontSize="8" MaxWidth="120" MaxHeight="14"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15 30 15 15">
            <Button Content="Introducere DAC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light" FontSize="8"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15 30 15 15">
            <Button Content="DAC iterativ" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light" FontSize="8"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="15 30 15 15">
            <Button Content="Probleme DAC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontSize="8" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

In such case you need just wrap each button to separate Grid with 4 columns and same width. Than if you will remove size and alignment from buttons and choose that button will be on 2nd and 3rd column.. you will get width of each button equal to 50% of width of parent column.

[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="home" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF00000F" FontFamily="./#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" FontSize="5"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Home" Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light" FontSize="8" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
           <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Introducere DAC"  Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light" FontSize="8"/>
        </Grid>
       
       <Grid  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>           
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="DAC iterativ"   Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light" FontSize="8"/>
        </Grid>
        
        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Probleme DAC"   Background="#FF00000F" Foreground="#FF77DFF1" BorderBrush="#FF77DFF1" FontSize="8" FontFamily="./#Roboto Condensed Light"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: "UniformGrid with proportional width" - I didn't know it exists

Comment: It isn't the correct answer, but it has definitely helped me. Thanks :)